# MockMvcResultMatchers - jsonPath() vs content()

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-restcontroller, mockmvc

I'm testing Spring REST controllers using `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc` object.
I can verify response JSON using `MockMvcResultMatchers.content()` method or `MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath()` method which accepts Hamcrest matcher. I'm wondering which approach is better and what are the best practices? With complicated structure Hamcrest matchers seems really hard to read, and with `content()`, long JSON has to be externalized to separate file (but it's not big deal IMHO). Should I prefer one option to another or it's completely personal thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `content()` when your response is not JSON. I.e. if the response is a plain text.

`jsonPath()` gives you more opportunities to check the response. 
For example

- you need only check a particular field;
- you need to check json-array, but you don't care about ordering;
- you compare for greater/less, but not exact matching,

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the payload you are manipulating.

If the payload is a short `String` with no moving values (like dates, etc.), you can go with plaintext comparison, maybe written using [hjson](https://hjson.org/) to improve readability.

On the other hand, if you have to test complex payloads, jsonPath are a good way to ease test reading.

In many cases, asserting that the payload is compliant with your json-schema is sufficient, as your business rules is tested in your domain package, so you just have to test the mapping from business objects to DTO.

In the rare case a majority of your tests are about testing **JSON** content, you may want to go with a specialized comparison tool like [JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit) and store payload templates in files.

In fine, if you are unit-testing (as in a test per method case), the only thing you are testing using `MockMvcResultMatchers#...` is the integration of your code with `spring-mvc` conventions.